# Getting like rows to combine in join query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am working on a query:

```
USE SCRUMAPI2

DECLARE @userParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@orgTeamPK VARCHAR(100)
    ,@statusParam VARCHAR(100)
    ,@search VARCHAR(100)
    ,@monthAgo VARCHAR(100)

SET @userParam = 'Amit Abc (abca)'
SET @orgTeamPK = '%'
SET @statusParam = '%'
SET @search = '%'
SET @monthAgo = '12/08/2013'

SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        ORDER BY TSK.[Status] DESC
        ) AS 'RowNumber'
    ,PDT.[Name] AS Project
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NOT NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NULL
                    )
                THEN 'KanBan'
            WHEN (
                    STY.KanBanProductId IS NULL
                    AND STY.SprintId IS NOT NULL
                    )
                THEN 'Sprint'
            END
        ) AS ProjectType
    ,STY.[Number] StoryNumber
    ,STY.Title AS StoryTitle
    ,CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), STY.Effort) AS StoryPoints
    ,(
        SELECT SUM(OriginalEstimateHours)
        FROM Task TSK
        LEFT JOIN Story STU ON TSK.StoryId = STU.PK_Story
        LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STU.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
        LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STU.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
        LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON TSK.PointPerson = USR.DisplayName
        WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
            AND (
                (
                    @orgTeamPK = '%'
                    AND (
                        USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                        OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                        )
                    )
                OR (
                    @orgTeamPK <> '%'
                    AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
                    )
                )
            AND STU.Number LIKE STY.Number
        ) AS StoryHoursEstimate
    ,ISNULL(SUM(DTH.[Hours]), 0) AS WorkHours
    ,'' AS Variance
    ,MAX(CASE 
            WHEN DTH.Hours != 0
                THEN DTH.ActivityDate
            END) AS LatestActivityDate
    ,(
        CASE 
            WHEN (TSK.[Status] = 'Not Started')
                THEN 'Active'
            WHEN (TSK.[Status] = 'In Progress')
                THEN 'Active'
            WHEN (TSK.[Status] = 'Impeded')
                THEN 'Active'
            WHEN (TSK.[Status] = 'Done')
                THEN 'Done'
            END
        ) AS [Status]
FROM Task TSK
LEFT JOIN DailyTaskHours DTH ON TSK.PK_Task = DTH.TaskId
LEFT JOIN Story STY ON TSK.StoryId = STY.PK_Story
LEFT JOIN Sprint SPT ON STY.SprintId = SPT.PK_Sprint
LEFT JOIN Product PDT ON STY.ProductId = PDT.PK_Product
LEFT JOIN [User] USR ON TSK.PointPerson = USR.DisplayName
WHERE TSK.PointPerson LIKE @userParam
    AND TSK.CreateDate >= CASE 
        WHEN TSK.[Status] = 'Done'
            THEN @monthAgo
        ELSE '1900-01-01'
        END
    AND TSK.[Status] LIKE @statusParam
    AND PDT.[Name] != 'Overhead Codes'
    AND (
        (
            @orgTeamPK = '%'
            AND (
                USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK
                OR USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] IS NULL
                )
            )
        OR (
            @orgTeamPK <> '%'
            AND (USR.[OrganizationalTeamId] LIKE @orgTeamPK)
            )
        )
    AND TSK.Deleted IS NULL
    AND (
        (
            STY.Number LIKE @search
            OR STY.Number IS NULL
            )
        OR (
            STY.Title LIKE @search
            OR STY.Title IS NULL
            )
        OR (
            TSK.NAME LIKE @search
            OR TSK.NAME IS NULL
            )
        )
GROUP BY LEN(STY.[Number])
    ,STY.[Number]
    ,TSK.[Status]
    ,STY.Title
    ,PDT.[Name]
    ,TSK.PointPerson
    ,TSK.CreateDate
    ,TSK.[Name]
    ,STY.KanBanProductId
    ,STY.SprintId
    ,TSK.OriginalEstimateHours
    ,STY.Effort
ORDER BY CASE TSK.[Status]
    WHEN 'Active'
        THEN 1
    WHEN 'Done'
        THEN 2
    END
```

Here are some results:

[image]

As is shown in the image, there are many instances of Story # PRO06-649. I want these to be combined on one line and on this line the current WorkHours in each current row would be summed for this column.

I believe what one of the things that is happening is that I am suming WorkHours at a level higher than I should.
How would I accomplish this?

Comment: What do you want for columns where the data is different on different rows? Latest activity date, for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not going to address your entire query, since it's [way more than necessary to demonstrate the problem](http://sscce.org/), but I'm going to provide a little insight into how to remove duplicates in general. Given this data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable
(
  Project VARCHAR(255), 
  ProjectType VARCHAR(32),  
  StoryNumber CHAR(9),
  WorkHours DECIMAL(10,2),
  LastActivityDate DATETIME,
  [Status] VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT dbo.mytable VALUES
('Procurement Project','Sprint','PRO06-262',0.00, NULL,'Active'),
('Procurement Project','Sprint','PRO06-649',5.00, '20140107','Active'),
('Other Systems',      'KanBan','MISCX-232',3.00, '20131230','Active'),
('Procurement Project','Sprint','PRO06-249',10.00,'20131219','Active'),
('Procurement Project','Sprint','PRO06-249',15.00,'20140103','Active'),
('Procurement Project','Sprint','PRO06-651',8.00, '20131213','Active');
GO
```

And making some guesses about what results you actually want, these are the two basic approaches:

1. **Use aggregates and `GROUP BY`.**

   ```
   SELECT Project, ProjectType, StoryNumber, wh = SUM(WorkHours), 
     la = MAX(LastActivityDate), st = MIN([Status])
   FROM dbo.MyTable
   GROUP BY Project, ProjectType, StoryNumber;
   ```

   This method is not very flexible because you'll often want, say, the status that goes with the latest activity date, for example, and there's no good way to express that purely with aggregates, without introducing complicated self-joins and multiple scans.
2. **Use CTEs and windowing functions.**

   ```
   ;WITH x AS 
   (
     SELECT Project, ProjectType, StoryNumber, 
       wh = SUM(WorkHours) OVER (PARTITION BY StoryNumber),
       rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY StoryNumber ORDER BY LastActivityDate DESC), 
   la = LastActivityDate, 
       st = [Status]
     FROM dbo.MyTable
   )
   SELECT Project, ProjectType, StoryNumber, wh, la, st FROM x WHERE rn = 1;
   ```

   This method is obviously more flexible, though it is more verbose and less intuitive.

Which method you choose depends on your requirements and which of these produces results that match what you're after (or could be tweaked to do so).

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need row number?

Also, unless you are ready to use an aggregate function on all the fields which have a distinct value - like workhours, storypoints etc, I don't feel there is a way to shrink multiple rows into one by grouping.

Comment: How would I use an aggregate function like this?

Comment: As you said, workhours need to be summed, you'll need to decide on aggregate function to be used for all other fields which differentiate 2 rows. Also, you may use Rank/Dense_rank instead of row number because row number will keep on incrementing

Comment: I'd suggest, push your current resultset to a temp table. Select from this temp table grouping on all fields except -workhours, storypoints, storyhoursestimate. Place a suitable aggregate function on these 3 fields and done.